# Font weights (normal, bold, ...)

Tags: css

I have three files for a font, the normal one, the bold one and the light one.
How can I set the light one on font-face, since font-weight:light does not exist?

By the way, is font-weight:lighter relative to something? If yes, to what?

Comment: font-weight:lighter is relative to the parent element. As per my answer below you should try font-weight:300 for a lighter version, it is possible the font file you have has multiple weights embedded!

Answer (score 0):

Try these (one at a time):

```
font-weight: lighter;
font-weight: 100;
font-weight: 200;
font-weight: 300;
```

Comment: I think lighter and bolder are relative to the computed font weight of the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get font that supports font-weight of different sizes, you should be able to specify the font weight as a number, for example:

```
font-weight:300 - should be light
font-weight:400 - should be normal
font-weight:700 - should be bold
```

But it will depend on how you are defining them in your font-face declaration, you should put the font weights in there, for example here is one for HelveticaNeue-Light

```
@font-face{
    font-family:"HelveticaNeue";
    src: url("/fonts/fontfile.eot");
    src: local('Helvetica Neue Light'), local('HelveticaNeue-Light'),
    url("/fonts/fontfile.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("/fonts/fontfile.woff") format("woff"),
    url("/fonts/fontfile.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("/fonts/fontfile.svg") format("svg");
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
}
```

Then you can use:

```
p {
    font-family:"HelveticaNeue"; 
    font-weight:300; 
}
```

And it will use that font-face definition, you can define multiple of these with different font-weights that match up to various files of different weights should you need to.

You can get font files that have multiple weights embedded into one file but most of the time now I believe the come in separately!

Comment: I've got a question for that.. Why so many font formats? And why do you have a file specially for IE? I've tested a .ttf font on IE and it worked if the font was on the same folder as the css/html. It stopped working once I put it on a font folder though.

Comment: Full cross browser support, especially for older versions of IE!

Comment: What if I have a font that only has the .ttf format? For example, the ubuntu one..

Comment: Then your embedded font wont work on certain browsers (mostly IE) : http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf